# How to find the correct iterative function for iterative method

Tags: numerical-methods

We want to compute the root of
$$f(x) = x^3-2x-5$$

Since $f(1.5)<0, f(2.5)>0$ the root must be within the interval $[1.5,2.5]$.

1) An intuitive iterative function would be $\phi(x) = 0.5 \cdot (x^3-5)$, that defines the iterative procedure:

$$x_{n+1} = 0.5 \cdot (x^3_n - 5)$$
but, it is not right because within the interval $[1.5, 2.5]$ there is $|\phi'(x)|>1$.

2) Another iterative function is $\phi(x) = (2x_n + 5)^{1/3}$, that defines the iterative procedure:

$$x_{n+1} = (2x_n+5)^{1/3}$$
and is ok because $1/6 < \phi'(x) < 0.15$. The procedure converges.

---

My questions:
- I don't understand what are the passages that bring to consider those iterative functions $\phi(x)$?

please, can you hep me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another iterative (polynomial) function.**

Since $f'(x)=3x^2-2$,  it follows that both $f$ and $f'$ are increasing in $[1.5,2.5]$ and therefore
$$f([1.5,2.5])=[f(1.5),f(2.5])]=[-4.625,5.625]$$ and 
$$f'([1.5,2.5])=[f'(1.5),f'(2.5])]=[4.75, 16.75].$$

Now consider the function
$$\phi(x):=x-\frac{f(x)}{M}$$
with $M>0$ large enough ($M=10$ works) such that
$$\phi([1.5,2.5])\subset [1.5,2.5]\qquad\text{and}\qquad\max_{x\in [1.5,2.5]} |\phi'(x)|<1.$$ 
Then the iterative method $x_{n+1}=\phi(x_n)$ for $n\geq 0$  with starting point $x_0\in [1.5,2.5]$ finds the unique fixed point of $\phi$ in $[1.5,2.5]$ which is the unique root of $f$ in $[1.5,2.5]$.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one sign change in the coefficient sequence, so that Descartes rule predicts exactly one positive real root.

A classical method to approximate positive roots is to find a form of the equation where all coefficients are positive
$$
x^3=2x+5
$$
and successively solve for the side with the higher degree
$$
x_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{2x_n+5}.
$$
This is what you verified as being successful.
\begin{align}
x_{0}&=2.000000000000\\
x_{1}&=2.080083823052\\
x_{2}&=2.092350677798\\
x_{3}&=2.094216996013\\
x_{4}&=2.094500652195\\
x_{5}&=2.094543757533\\
\end{align}

---

Another approach is to use that you already found that the root is close to $2$ and perform polynomial division by $x-2$,
$$
0=(x-2)(x^2+2x+2)-1
$$
and derive the iteration
$$
x_{n+1}=2+\frac1{(x_n+1)^2+1}
$$
\begin{align}
x_{0}&=2.000000000000\\
x_{1}&=2.100000000000\\
x_{2}&=2.094250706880\\
x_{3}&=2.094568125667\\
x_{4}&=2.094550560622\\
x_{5}&=2.094551532497\\
\end{align}

---

A more systematic approach would be to use the simplified Newton method starting at the guessed location of the root
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(2)}=x_n-\frac{x^3-2x-5}{10}
$$
\begin{align}
x_{0}&=2.000000000000\\
x_{1}&=2.100000000000\\
x_{2}&=2.093900000000\\
x_{3}&=2.094626880398\\
x_{4}&=2.094542720862\\
x_{5}&=2.094552498993\\
\end{align}
or the full Newton method, using some modification $f(x)=x^2-2-5x^{-1}$ of the equation for variety
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-2-5x_n^{-1}}{2x_n+5x_n^{-2}}
=x_n\frac{x_n^3+2x_n+10}{2x_n^3+5}
$$
\begin{align}
x_{0}&=2.000000000000\\
x_{1}&=2.095238095238\\
x_{2}&=2.094551521901\\
x_{3}&=2.094551481542\\
x_{4}&=2.094551481542\\
x_{5}&=2.094551481542\\
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, one question: why $x_0 = 2.000000000000$?

Comment: @JB-Franco : Because it is the middle point of the interval you identified as to contain a root.